# How to use namespacing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modularize my code by adding 'namespace' functionality using jQuery, I need to be able to access variables and functions throughout different files. What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: You can use requirejs http://requirejs.org/, browserify http://browserify.org/ and even webpack https://webpack.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access functions from other files, as well as pass variables to them like this:

`myFunction.js`

```
myExampleNameSpace: {
      myTestFunction: function(variable) {
          alert('this is my variable' + variable);
      }
}
```

now you can talk to it like this:

`main.js`

```
myExampleNameSpace.myTestFunction("a string!");
```